# other bean is getting called before Profile bean in boot

Tags: spring-boot, properties-file

I have a Spring boot application, I have multiple beans configured in main class and I also have different profiles set for different environments. Please see the code below:

```
private static String propertiesFilePath;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOGGER.info("Starting app..!!");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    @Profile("local")
    public  String localBean() {
        propertiesFilePath = "application-local.properties";
        return propertiesFilePath;
    }

    @Bean
    public static CommandLineRunner init() {
        return (args) -> {
            try {
                LOGGER.info("Starting ..");
                CommonUtil.initializeCacheManager(propertiesFilePath);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.info("CommonUtil.initializeCacheManager :" + e.getMessage());
            }
        };

    }

    @Bean
    public BroadcastHandler createBroadcastHandler() {
        return new BroadcastHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
```

In this code, other beans are getting called first then the bean annotated with @Profile, I can see in logs below line:

> The following profiles are `active: local`

Since Spring container is trying to initialize other beans so without property getting initialized first, the application is failing to start.

Is there any reason why bean with @Profile is not getting called and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Spring boot doesn't work with profiles like you've presented in the code snippet in the question.

It resolves all the profiles resolution automatically and loads corresponding beans (annotated with `@Profle` annotation):

When you run the application, add `--spring.profiles.active=local` to the command that executes the java application.

This alone will instruct spring boot to look for `application-local.properties` (or yaml) and will resolve all the properties from there just like it works with usual `application.properties` processed by default.

The properties files by default will be resolved if you place it into `src/main/resources` or `src/main/resources/config` folders.

There is also a way to enable profiles automatically from java code (with Environment Post Processors) but it's beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
spring.profiles.active=local
```

in your application.properties file.

Comment: I have this line in application.properties file that is why I am getting this line in log "The following profiles are active: local"

Comment: You don't have to explicitly tell your spring application to load the application-local.properties file. Anything annotated with @Profile("local") will definitely get its configuration from the application-local.properties. Try removing the localBean and CommandLineRunner beans.